# How to show pdf form fields name on pdf (with open source php method)

Tags: php, pdf, yii

Is there a way to display the pdf form fields name on the PDF with php , nay command line tool . I am using php(yii) and pdftk for pdf filling and other pdf handling function  .

I am using this to fill the form

```
pdftk /var/www/immitrax/uploads/forms/DirectDepositForm.pdf fill_form /var/www/immitrax/uploads/temp/posted-17.fdf output -
```

and this to get the form fields

```
pdftk http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_014.pdf dump_data_fields
```

I am done a lot of R&D on this .But fails to know any solution . please help me .

just like in this image .i just want to show the field name on the pdf . I am successfull to display the field name on the text . but can't on the checkboxes, radio button etc
[image]

Comment: Do you want to show the form field names ON the PDF pages or simply access these information with php? Do you also want to fill in the fields with PHP but via CLI?

Comment: i just want to show the field name on the pdf . I am successfull to display the field name on the text . but can't on the checkboxes, radio button etc .

Comment: please check the screenshot here http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/259625/d5c48b21d5dc292268f84bb19b1ba688